# Use a multiline variable in git tag message preserving line breaks

Tags: bash, git, github, tags

I have a multiline variable `$foo`, and want to use it to git tag my latest commit. I would like those line breaks to show up in git (/github). I tried

```
git tag -a v$MAJVER.$MINVER.$PATVER.$HOTVER -m $"$foo"
```

[image: but it shows up like this, so without line breaks rendering]

How can I make it (via bash) such that line breaks survive the push?

Comment: Can you show how is the variable `$foo` defined? or rather how do you add a line break? Also you have an extra `$` after the `-m`

Comment: I do not trust that interface. What is the output of `git show`? Does the comment have the line breaks there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use simple double-quoting. If that isn't working, it's something in the value.

If what's concerning you is the output *of* the commit, that is just a report.
Go look at the actual log.

```
$: ls -l
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 P2759474 1049089 474 Nov  2 14:22 tst

$: mv tst new
$: git status
On branch tst
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        deleted:    tst

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        new

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$: foo="
    testing
    multiline
    git
    commit
    message
"

$: git add .
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in new.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory

$: git commit -m "$foo" # keeps newlines, but shows without them
[tst 74428e6]     testing     multiline     git     commit     message
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename tst => new (100%)

$: git log -1
commit 74428e60d830c417ded3ad2c331f02e73319b862 (HEAD -> tst)
Author: Paul Hodges <paul.hodges@redacted.com>
Date:   Thu Nov 3 10:20:33 2022 -0500

        testing
        multiline
        git
        commit
        message
```

The same works with tags, but you have to know how to get the data back out.

```
$: git tag -a example -m "$foo"

$: git tag -l
example

$: git tag -n
example             testing

$: git tag -n99
example             testing
        multiline
        git
        commit
        message
```

You have to tell it how many lines of the message you are willing to have it show you. The default is 1.

Comment: Thankis, I got it to work now. Strange why it did not work before.